# Non competitve agreement during probation period

Tags: contract-law, employment, non-compete

Quick question- does the non competitive agreement apply during the probation period of 6 months? Or is that depending on the company?.. Im waiting for my contract to come through as i recently got a job offer. I am also waiting for an interview for another job in the similar field and position and if i get that job then im most likely to consider it.

Any advice/ help is much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: There's no uniform non-competitive agreement, nor is there a uniform probation persiod, so the answer would depend entirely on the terms of your contract with your previous employer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implied restraint, except possibly a duty of fidelity and confidentiality to the employer by the employee.

Generally, in fact, there is a presumption *against* restraints as it interferes with the common law right to contract, etc., unless it is explicitly agreed to by the parties.

If there's no restraint in your contract, there's no restraint.